# Can't change Column to array - int64

Tags: python, arrays

I have a CSV dataset with 2 columns that looks like the following:

| Date | Open |
| --- | --- |
| 25/2/21 | 7541.85 |
| 26/2/21 | 7562.32 |
| 27/2/21 | 7521.65 |
| 28/2/21 | 7509.14 |

Data columns (total 2 columns):

| # | Column | Non-Null | Count | Dtype |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Open | 1280 | non-null | object |
| 1 | Date | 1280 | non-null | datetime64[ns] |

dtypes: datetime64ns, object(1)

When trying to pass this through a timeseries model I get the following error:

`ftse_open = TimeSeries.from_dataframe(ftse_open, time_col='Date', value_cols='Open')`

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: '7,541.85'

Then I try a different route using the following code:

`ftse_open["Open"] = ftse_open["Open"].astype('Int64')`

Yielding:

> TypeError: object cannot be converted to an IntegerDtype

I have tried more code to resolve but I'm not sure why there seems to be no solution that I can find.

(There are no NAs in the dataset - I have checked).

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: So, `Open` column contains strings in format `7,541.85` for example?

Comment: Something like this, yes, the dtype for the Open column is an object in string format. But every time I try to convert this to a float I get the first error^.

Comment: I think it may be the punctuation in the string that cannot be converted. I will try to get rid of the ","

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comments, you can try:

```py
df["Open"] = df["Open"].str.replace(",", "").astype(float)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
      Date     Open
0  25/2/21  7541.85
1  26/2/21  7562.32
2  27/2/21  7521.65
3  28/2/21  7509.14
```

---

`df` used:

```
      Date      Open
0  25/2/21  7,541.85
1  26/2/21  7,562.32
2  27/2/21  7,521.65
3  28/2/21  7,509.14
```